# Create an user in the DB using sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I can create an user in my DB, using sequelize. Part of my controller is:

```
db.User.findAll()
      .then(function(Users){

//Creation
db.User.create({
   userName:emailName[0],
   email: req.body.email,//We add the email of the user
   password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password,10), //The password is hashed
   image: req.file.filename//We add the image of the user
   })
})
```

But in this point I want to save this user into the sesion variable "user", such as:

```
 let loggedUser = Users[Users.length-1] //To save the last user
 req.session.user=loggedUser
```

but if I use the console to visualize all the User, the last one is not already created at this point.

```
 console.log(Users.length)
```

It returns the length without the last user

So, how can I force the creation of the user in this point? in order of accessing to all its properties (such its id, name, and so on). I'm using mysql

Comment: Could you show a bit more of code between `findAll` and `create`? It's not clear how you wait for the `create` result and use it later